# How to listen eventBus value in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, event-bus

I'm trying to get search input value, but it fails.

**Here I'm sending values by event bus:**

```js
import eventBus from "../../../services/eventBus";

export default {
    name: "Navbar",
    data() {
        return {
            searchInputValue: '',

        }
    },
    watch: {
        searchInputValue(val) {
            eventBus.$emit("search", val);
        }
    }
}
```

**Here I'm trying to get values:**

```js
import eventBus from "./services/eventBus";

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            searchInputValue: null
        }
    },
    created() {
        eventBus.$on("search", data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
}
```

**eventBus**

```js
import Vue from 'vue' 

const eventBus = new Vue(); 

export default eventBus;
```

But I get this error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: _services_eventBus__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default.a.$on is not a function"

Comment: Possibly a path resolution issue `import eventBus from "./services/eventBus"`.

Comment: Could you share your EventBus code?

Comment: @Hammerbot ```import Vue from 'vue'
const eventBus = new Vue();
export default eventBus;```

Comment: @jom pathes are correct

Comment: Maybe you should use `import eventBus from "../../../services/eventBus";` in your listener component. Can you run `console.log(eventBus)` in your listener component?

Comment: @sedatsevgili these two components are not in the same folder

Comment: ok, what is the output of the `console.log(eventBus)` in your listener component?

Comment: @sedatsevgili an empty object ``` Object
__proto__:
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

Comment: Are you using single file components?

Comment: @Taylor there are two components

Comment: did you try binding search to the component you are trying to send it to?

Answer (score 0):

well I don't know the exact reason but if you do single import in your eventBus.js the error will go away what is am trying to say is do this in your eventBus.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
export default new Vue();
```